# If we install "modified games" on our iPhone or iPad, what risks are we exposing ourselves to?

Tags: iphone, applications, security

For example, through TweakBox, AppValley, or even some website, we can install some "mod" or "modified games" (such as a Pacman that never dies, or a game that requires your location but the app can emulate the GPS location).

We have to go to Settings and "trust" the app. If we trust the app, to what extend of risks are we exposed to?  I don't believe the app can go to the Mail or Gmail app and look at our emails, for example. The only thing I can think of is that it fakes a log in screen to your iTunes account and lead you to type in the user name and password (Trojan horse), so I will always cancel such log in popup and go to iTunes and log in there myself.

Comment: This would make a great [chat] room to hash out experiences if people want to discuss this topic.

Answer (score 1):

#### Strongly recommend not to install such apps via any such (untrusted) medium

There's a likelihood that you may be exposing yourself to innumerable risks. These apps are distributed by gaming the Apple Developer Enterprise license.

They are distributed without going through the standard Apple's App Store Review Process. So it's likely that *may* be breaking one or more review guidelines and posing risk to the security of device and data.

Apple continuously discovers and suspend enterprise licenses where they are gamed to distribute apps to general public without going through the App Store Review process. Enterprise license is created solely for the purpose of distributing apps within an enterprise, and not to general public.

- [Apple's Enterprise Developer Program Also Being Used to Distribute Hacked Apps](https://www.macrumors.com/2019/02/13/apple-enterprise-program-hacked-apps/)

---

> The only I can think of is that it fakes a log in screen to your iTunes account and lead you to type in the user name and password (Trojan horse), so I will always cancel such log in popup and go to iTunes and log in there myself.

If you are concerned about this particular risk, i.e. an app presenting a **fake** iTunes login popup and stealing password, there's an easy way to trust it's authenticity.

Just press the Home button (or on devices without Home button, navigate back to Home screen). If the popup is presented by the app (fake), it will be sent to the background along with the app. If the popup is presented by iOS (genuine), pressing Home button won't let you dismiss it. You will be able to dismiss it either by entering password or the pressing the cancel button.

Comment: You may want to expand on innumerable risks.  If the 'hack' is emulating GPS then it has full control of other hardware.  Some of the Google hacks like this have placed phone calls without owners knowledge, eavesdropped on calls, read e-mails and texts and then there is the good old fashioned key logger.  Long story short you are installing a 'hack', what it is 'hacking' is always an unknown.

Comment: Can an app read emails and log key strokes? I thought the app is usually sandboxed and has its own universe...  now if it is installing an app on the PC, then it might be a different situation, because the app probably can go to some of your folders and look around (such as in the old days if you use Netscape mail to download your emails to your PC). Key logging possible on the PC too. And for using hardware on the iPhone, don't you have to give explicit permission? (pressing YES or go to Settings to do it)

Comment: @太極者無極而生 The installed app cannot read other apps data. So, it cannot read your emails. Can it log keystrokes? It can log keystrokes from the activity happening in the app itself but not other apps. If the app that you installed is a custom keyboard app, it can read keystrokes from any app across iOS.

Comment: @ThomasNelson if it is to emulate the GPS location, the "mod" app might not access the hardware. The hacker only needs to change every line that looks up the GPS location using the OS call to call another function that returns the desired GPS location. So it is not even touching the hardware at all but rather, skipping it.